# Input statement following a print statement prints first

Tags: python

I have a print statement preeceeding and input statement. However the input statement prints first.

```
print('Warning this program renames files')
char =input ('Enter  Y to continue N to quit')
```

The terminal screen the results are:

```
Enter Y to continue N to quit
Warning this program renames files
```

if I introduce some form of delay between the two statements it works correctly. Example code:

```
print('Warning this program renames files')
for i in range (1,10000):
    j=i*i
char=input('Enter  Y to continue N to quit')
```

the output  in the terminal is printed in the correct order

```
Warning this program renames files
Enter  Y to continue N to quit
```

Anyone know why this happens it looks like a race between the two statement to access the print functions and input seems to win unless you delay its execution.

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce this. What version of Python, and what OS and terminal are you using? Is this inside a function or just the top level of the script?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than a delay, try

```
import sys

print('Warning this program renames files')
sys.stdout.flush()
char = input('Enter  Y to continue N to quit')
```